# How to check if inside an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, if-statement

I have the following in `menu.php`. I need to check whether Session is ok. But I am getting **Parse error**.

I looked on same questions but I couldn't find out what I want.

```
<?php

$menu=array();

if(Session::get("home")) {
        $menu[]=array(
            "label" => "Home",
            "link" => APP_ABS_PATH
        );
}

if(Session::get("about"))
{
    $menu[]=array(
        "label" => "About",
        "link" => APP_ABS_PATH.'about'
    )
}

if(Session::get("contact"))
{
    $menu[]=array(
        "label" => "Contact",
        "link" => APP_ABS_PATH.'contact'
    )
}

return $menu;

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can check like this whether the value is exists in an array if(in_array())

Comment: Could you show the parse error message? 
and it seem that you are using some plugin or php framework to control ? is it  right

Comment: @ToujouAya Following answer is correct. I have missed the semicolon.

Comment: @user2584538 ok fine, i was thought , the semicolon missed when you copy paste code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just missed `;` after array

```
if(Session::get("about"))
{
    $menu[]=array(
        "label" => "About",
        "link" => APP_ABS_PATH.'about'
    );
}

if(Session::get("contact"))
{
    $menu[]=array(
        "label" => "Contact",
        "link" => APP_ABS_PATH.'contact'
    );
}
```